# How to hide an element by value, if a radio button is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've given 3 radio boxes as below,

```
    <input type="radio" class="minimal" name="statusFilter" value="1" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="radio" class="minimal" name="statusFilter" value="2" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="radio" class="minimal" name="statusFilter" value="3" autocomplete="off">
```

Here, I need to hide an element if the radio button with value 2 is checked. I've tried with the below code but '**hide is active for all the radio buttons**.

```
    $('input[name="statusFilter"]').each(function() {
           if ($(this).val() == 2) {
           alert('test');
            $('#btn-create-proforma').hide();
       }
    });
```

Comment: Please note you have a `"` to many in each `autocomplete="off""`

Comment: You could just add `$('#btn-create-proforma').show();` before your `if`.  But depends on when you run your code, which you've not provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should listen to event `onChange` instead

Besides, you can use `toggle` to trigger show/hide to enhance the logic like this.

```js
$('input[name="statusFilter"]').on("change", function() {
   const isEqualTo_2 = $(this).val() != 2;
   $('#btn-create-proforma').toggle(isEqualTo_2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="minimal" name="statusFilter" value="1" autocomplete="off">
<input type="radio" class="minimal" name="statusFilter" value="2" autocomplete="off">
<input type="radio" class="minimal" name="statusFilter" value="3" autocomplete="off">

<button id="btn-create-proforma">btn-create-proforma</button>
```

---

**Explain:**

- When you listen to `onChange` event. Whenever you click the radio button, the callback function will be affected. Now you can check the value to display/hide button as you wish.
- `toggle` internally works like, if a condition is true, then `element.show()` if it's false, `element.hide()`.

Comment: Yes, when you listen to `onChange` event. Whenever you click the radio button, the callback function will be affected. Now you can check the value to `toggle` button as you wish. https://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Okay, then toggle internally works like,
if a condition is true, then element.show()
if it's false, element.hide()?

Comment: Yes. It's the same as `show/hide` but shorter, more concise ^^! @Naveen

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').on('change', 'input[name="statusFilter"]', function(){
    var dis = $(this),
        showHide = dis.val() != 2;

    $('#btn-create-proforma').toggle(showHide);
});
```